# timer crashes with KotlinNullPointerException inside fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I created Timer (java.util.Timer) in Kotlin this way:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener({
        val timer = Timer("schedule", true)
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(1000, 1000) {
            if (timerViewModel?.timerValue?.value!! > 0){
                timerViewModel?.timerValue?.value = timerViewModel?.timerValue?.value!! - 1
                activity.runOnUiThread { textViewTimer.text = timerViewModel?.timerValue?.value?.toString() }
            } else {
                cancel()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

This code crashes on 5th line with the error:

```
 kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
           at com.dmitry.timer.views.TimerFragment$onViewCreated$1$$special$$inlined$scheduleAtFixedRate$1.run(Timer.kt:145)
           at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

When I create timer inside `activity` - it works fine.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like `textViewTimer` or `activity` is null on this line:

```
activity.runOnUiThread{...}
```

Are you sure you've set it up appropriately?

In particular, you cannot rely on `Fragment.getActivity()` (just `activity` here in Kotlin) to return a non-null value at arbitrary points after creation. Because you are executing this in a timer, it is possible for `getActivity` to return null.

Aside: The stack traces can be confusing when using nested lambdas like this. If you look carefully at

```
at com.dmitry.timer.views.TimerFragment$onViewCreated$1$$special$$inlined$scheduleAtFixedRate$1.run(Timer.kt:145)
```

You can see the `$1` after `scheduleAtFixedRate`. That dollar-sign notation is often used to refer to anonymous methods or lambdas, and here I believe it is referring to your timer handler itself.

Comment: you are right. The mistake was inside lambda. The crush really looks confusing :( thanks

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer by Myk Willis, you are combining the safe-call (`.?`) as well as the NPE-call (`!!`) operators.

This means that if `timerViewModel`, `timerViewModel.timerValue` or `timerViewModel.timerValue.value` is `null` then that can also cause the NPE that you're seeing. Effectively negating the benefit of using the safe-call operator.